# I am getting success response while uploading PDF in jmeter, but file is not uploaded

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

while uploading PDF document in Jmeter, I am getting sucess response({"validation_error":0,"msg":"Files Uploaded Successfully"}) but in request i am getting this error(<actual file content, not shown here>) and when i check for document upload it is not uploaded

Answer (score 0):

This is not an "error", as per [PostWriter JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/PostWriter.html#sendPostData-java.net.URLConnection-org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase-)

> **Returns**:
>
> the post body sent. Actual file content is not returned, it is just shown as a placeholder text "actual file content"

The question why your file doesn't get uploaded cannot be answered as we don't know what does your server expect and how do you configure the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

If you can successfully upload the file using your browser (or other application) I would suggest just recording this using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure to copy your PDF file to JMeter's "bin" folder prior to the uploading and JMeter will create the relevant HTTP Request sampler correctly and automatically. More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)